# Loading an application from Eclipse to a real Android device over wifi

Tags: android

I read many articles on how we can launch an Android emulator faster.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator/2049798#2049798) where *user286101* said that he "can load the app over wifi onto the real device in a fraction of the time".

My question is : how can I load an application, from Eclipse, to my real device through wifi ?

Regards.

Comment: did any go these ideas work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you must connect adb to your device using the command line: `adb connect <host>[:<port>]`. Then Eclipse will adb your device over WiFi.

Check out the [adb docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is adb wireless : http://www.appbrain.com/app/siir.es.adbWireless

butt your phone has to be rooted

Comment: Is there any other "unrooted" alternative ?

Comment: that is the only app I found :(

Answer (score 0):

I do it all the time via [dropbox.com](http://dropbox.com) takes just a matter of seconds.

Just move the .apk to your dropbox folder and then open it from your device. This will work for both wifi and 3G.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bytebender's suggestion, you can transfer your apk with kies air as well, and run it by locating it with your Android's file browser. It's not exactly launching from eclipse, but this is what I had to do because I didn't have an OEM usb connector and the 3rd party (cheap) ones I had weren't connecting to my PC. I couldn't get the adb method to work. My phone does not have ROOT access.